# ServiceProvider not loaded

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Im trying to setup a facade for my Gravatar library.

#### Problem

The problem I have is the following,the ServiceProvider does not get registert. So 'gravatar' is not in the IoC.

I added `\Log::info('initialized');` to my ServiceProvider but nothing is logged.

#### Error

`Call to undefined method Facade\Gravatar::getUrl()`

#### Code

http://paste.laravel.com/AgO

Comment: Do you have auto-loading of your library setup in `composer.json`? Can you show us your "autoload" portion in that file?

Comment: it is loaded and dumpautoload is used. `"app/providers", "app/facades"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, a Facade takes (potential) three classes:

1. The class which has the methods you'll use, in this case `Gravatar::getUrl()`
2. The Facade class which tells Laravel where to find the class in point 1
3. The ServiceProvider, which creates the class with the methods, via the $app container.

See here on [creating facades in Laravel](http://fideloper.com/create-facade-laravel-4) for some more info.

In your case, I don't see the code from point 1.

#### The class

Libraries/Gravatar/Avatar.php

```
<?php namespace Gravatar;

class Avatar {

    public function getUrl() { ...  }

}
```

#### The Facade

Libraries/Gravatar/Facade.php

```
<?php namespace Gravatar;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade as BaseFacade;

class Facade extends BaseFacade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() {
    return 'gravatar';
}

}
```

#### The Service Provider

Libraries/Gravatar/GravatarServiceProvider.php

```
<?php namespace Gravatar;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider

class GravatarServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register() {
    Log::info('initialized');
    $this->app['gravatar'] = $this->app->share(function () {
        return new Avatar();
    });
}

}
```

#### Tie together in `app/config/app.php`

```
<?php
'providers' => array(
...
'Gravatar\GravatarServiceProvider'
),
'aliases' => array(
...
'Gravatar'        => 'Gravatar\Facade'
),
```

#### Note

Note that I the namespace I used assumes this directory structure:

```
Libraries
    Gravatar
        Avatar.php
        GravatarServiceProvider.php
        Facade.php
```

With autoloading like this in `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "Gravatar": "app/Library" // Or wherever your Library directory is
    }
},
```

If you're confused on Namespacing and how that works with autoloading, read up on [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/0/).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Using it all in 1 folder worked. Ty (code still the same except namespaces)

Comment: Great! If that's a working solution, free feel to check it off as "accepted", under the up/down vote buttons so others know it's a working solution